# Auto Update entity framework model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

Is it possible to automatically update a model using entity framework after modifying the database?

Comment: Check this out here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is !

Double click on your .edmx file, Model Browser will open up.

Right click on the edmx file and select the **Update Model from Database** option.

[image]

Comment: I like how you blanked out the "B*******E*****" at the top and at the bottom, but not in the middle.

Comment: did that too ! privacy concerns ;)

Comment: It looks like manually update to me ... how about after deploying to Azure? does the model automatically update too?