# Update Model in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am trying to make a MVC 3 application that use Entity framework.I use Entity Framework Database First.I made an Sql Server Database with 2 tables ,then i generated with entity framework the model,classes .Then I added an other  2 columns to one of the table.How to update my MVC model with this colums?Exist an automatic way to do this (a command that i  can runn to bring all the modifications in my model)?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Update entity framework model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687264/auto-update-entity-framework-model). Did you look at the "Questions that may already have your answer" when you asked this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at the designer or code view? You can force the designer to open by right clicking on your EDMX file and selecting `Open With -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer`

Right click on the designer surface of the EDMX designer and click `Update Model From Database...`

All entities are refreshed by default, new entities are only added if you select them.

Answer (score -2):

Select your xxx.edmx file.
CTRL + A to select all the tables, and then press DELETE to delete them.
right click UpdateModel, select your tabels, views, stored procedures, and include them.
CTRL + S to save and automatically generate the model partial classes